# Do while loop until user enters valid input

Tags: javascript

I need to create a do while loop that accepts any user input until a number is entered. my loop doesn't execute as expected. please help.
can i do without the maximum and the minimum values?

```js
var number;
var minimum = 1;
var maximum = 20
window.prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 20");
do {


  if (number >= minimum && number <= maximum)
    break;
  else(window.prompt("Invalid input, please enter a number between 
        1 and 20 "));
      }
      while (number < minimum || number > maximum);
```

Comment: u can not ever do loops waiting for userinput in code, unless you have things like Application.DoEvents() from C#, but also this would be very bad to use in a loop. Use events or delegates or something that javascript supports.

Comment: @Livo it's not fancy but `prompt()` does in fact work

Comment: When the syntax error is fixed the code as posted almost works fine. You have a string (the error message) split across two lines, and that doesn't work (as coded). Also `window.prompt()` returns  a value, and you  have to actually save that in the variable `number`.

Comment: @Pointy, yeah true, its javascript.. so a lot is accepted.

Comment: @Pointy, except number will always be `undefined` - how would javascript know you want the user entered value to be stored in `number`?

Comment: @JaromandaX yea you're right of course but it stopped asking when I typed "5" :)

Comment: @Pointy you could type ANYTHING :p - because undefined < minimum and  undefined > maximum are both false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below works for you.

It's basically the same as yours, but I made it much more efficient and readable.

A few things I changed for you was:

1. `window.prompt` and `prompt` do the same thing. In other words, the `window` is unnecessary typing, so use just `prompt`.
2. `prompt` alone just asks for an input. It doesn't store it anywhere, or do anything with it. For you to be able to do anything with it, you need to set the value of a variable to equal it. I set `number` to equal the `prompt`
3. You can use [`isNan()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if it is a string or a number.

```js
var number = prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 20");
var minimum = 1;
var maximum = 20

do {
  if (isNaN(number)) {
    break;
  }
  else {
    number = prompt("Please enter a valid number between 1 and 20");
  }
}
while (!isNaN(number));
```

Comment: Thanks Aniket but am trying to actually write a code that is gonna accept any user input unless its a number. i used minimum and maximum coz i could figure out a way to do it, other wise the question is " write a do while loop that accepts any user input until a number is entered"

Comment: @jojo fixed it.